# generate SSL keystore and private key for jboss6

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ssl, ssl-certificate, keystore

I want to make my own SSL certificate in-order to be used in a web application. When I try to generate the keystore I get this error. I inserted my own new password to it. Is there anything specific to put as password?

***windows commandline***

```
C:\jboss6\server\default\conf>keytool -genkey -alias jbosskey -keypass change_this -keyalg RSA -keystore server.keystore
Enter keystore password:
```

***error which is displayed***

```
keytool error: java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a good descriptive solution to my issue on following link, and it worked for me.

[JBOSS https/ssl configuration](http://sudipta05.wordpress.com/web/jboss-httpsssl-configuration/)

Answer (score 1):

Works for me without -keypass.

```
keytool -genkey -alias jbosskey -keyalg RSA -keystore server.keystore
```

Comment: it gives "keytool error: java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect" error